# Class constructor with structure components

Tags: c++

I am defining a constructor in a class that takes in 5 arguments to initialize the fields. Two of those arguments/field come from a `Date` structure.

```
Information(string NewName, Date start, Date finish,
            double newNumber, double newLevel);
```

Is this the proper format for doing so?

Also, how would I go about inputting the arguments in `int main ()` ? Something like this?  How do I go about putting values into the structure arguments? Do they go into quotes?

```
Information arguments("Susan Jones", "3/5/5", "3/5/5", 15, 58);
```

Date structure:

```
 struct Date
  {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
  };
```

Comment: Could you please define "proper"? I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @thiton Ich meine, ist dies der richtige Weg es zu tun?

Comment: "Richtig" has many meanings and many viewpoints. A more concrete question would help.

Comment: @thiton Ich fragte eine spezielle Frage in den Kommentaren unter dem ersten Antwort.

Comment: @user22507: What can you tell us about the constructors for the `Date` structure?  There is no standard `Date` structure, so we can't tell you anything about it.  (If it has no constructors, what members does it have?)

Comment: @MooingDuck question updated with Date structure.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to pass const references to non-basic types used in the constructor. So make Data `const&` instead of just copies. To be more specific:

```
Information(const string& NewName,const Date& start,const Date& finish,
          double newNumber, double newLevel);
```

Also assuming that Date has a constructor taking an `std::string` or `const char*` the way you call the constructor is correct(although it seems you are calling the constructor of another class called `Paycheck`).

Otherwise the code seems reasonable.

Comment: how do I go about inputting into the structure arguments? Do they go into quotes?

Comment: @user22507 no you simply call the constructor of the given argument so assuming Date has a constructor taking 3 ints as arguments you do:
`Information arguments("Susan Jones", Date(3,5,5), Date(3,5,5), 15, 58);`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: That depends entirely on the constructors of the `Date` class, and if it's implicitly constructable from a string.  But what you suggest is more likely.

Comment: @MooingDuck I said assuming Date has a constructor... So of course it does depend on the class Date

Answer (score 0):

The `Information` constructor you show looks reasonable.  For medium or large objects, you might want to pass by `const Date&` instead of just `Date`, but for small/simple/fast objects like you have, making copies shouldn't be that big of a deal.  Here's the "normal" way:

```
Information(const string& NewName, const Date& start, const Date& finish,
      double newNumber, double newLevel);
```

However, `"3/5/5"` is not the right way to construct an instance of `Date`.  There's two ways, both shown below.  The first is easier to understand, but the second is far less code.

```
Date start;
start.month = 3;
start.day = 5;
start.year = 5;

Date finish;
start.month = 3;
start.day = 5;
start.year = 5;

Information arguments("Susan Jones", start, finish, 15, 58);
```

or

```
Information arguments("Susan Jones", {3,5,5}, {3,5,5}, 15, 58);
```

Comment: thank you -- how would I declare the constructor in the class?

Comment: @user22507: What?  How would you declare what destructor in what class?